# Google Sheets - Filtering emails from the text in a cell

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, array-formulas, email-validation

Using the below I'm able to get just the first email from C1, but no emails from the subsequent cells. I need to be able to get all the emails from all the cells. How do I modify this to work on the next cells also? (C2 to C4)?

(I found part of a solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/946293/extracting-email-from-text-string-in-excel-google-spreadsheet) But it's only able to get an email from one cell).

```
  =iferror(Regexextract(test!C1:C4,"[A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,4}"),"")
```

Here's my test Google Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_VEdYMSfgFWLvyyFa99xWLNsH6YBgZrcncG4neSvXhE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(test!C1:C, 
 "[A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,4}")))
```

[image]